# MySQL disable all triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, information-schema

For test correctness of query I need disable all triggers in db.
I see that in information_schema exists table TRIGGERS.
Is possible temporarily disable all triggers using this table?
E.g. like:

```
update TRIGGERS set TRIGGERS_SCHEMA='myschema_new' 
where TRIGGERS_SCHEMA='myschema'
```

and after finish all test return all triggers like:

```
update TRIGGERS set TRIGGERS_SCHEMA='myschema'
where TRIGGERS_SCHEMA='myschema_new'
```

May be this can corrupt db or after triggers will not works? I didn't found about it in documentation.

Comment: The `information_schema` tables can't be modified anyway. They're actually views: [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html).

Comment: @Joel B Fant - +1 I had no idea. Thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't disable triggers directly and I wouldn't recommend doing what you're suggesting but you could have your trigger check if a variable (in my example below `@disable_triggers`) is  `NULL` before executing the trigger's content. For example:

**Query:**

```
SET @disable_triggers = 1;
// Your update statement goes here.
SET @disable_triggers = NULL;
```

**Triggers:**

```
IF @disable_triggers IS NULL THEN
    // Do something use as the trigger isn't disabled.
END IF;
```

Comment: I have near 1000 triggers - it very difficult to do what you recomend.

Comment: @Lorenzo Manucci - I'm afraid that there isn't a way to disable or enable triggers in MySQL. You should either recreate all of the triggers if this is something you'll need to do on a constant basis or recreate them if they're not working properly. I'm not entirely convinced that modifying the `information_schema` database is a good idea but if it solves your problem and this is a 1 time thing, backup your all your databases and go for it.

Comment: Check the current value using `SELECT @disable_triggers;`

Comment: @LorenzoManucci I did a generation script. I actually also something like this:     


```sql
IF (@DISABLE_ALL_TRIGGERS IS NULL AND @DISABLE_TRIGGER_MOST_YOUR_SPECIFIC_TRIGGER IS NULL) THEN
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to 'disable' triggers in mysql, however a trick that can be used to get around this

Add a condition in your triggers like:

```
if (DISABLE_TRIGER <> 1 ) then 
#trigger body 
end if;
```

and than if you want to disable triggers on import just:

SET @DISABLE_TRIGER = 1;

do imports

```
SET @DISABLE_TRIGER = 0;
```

Comment: And also I cannot change the code of triggers because I am not the author - these triggers will fix another person because they work not correct, but I need to finish my work - to test all querys for insert.