# MySQL slow_query_log reporting more Rows_examined than rows in table (no joins)

Tags: mysql

When refactoring my `entries`table and pulling the `source` column into a separate `sources` table , I'm performing an UPDATE which you can see in the below `slow_query_log`.

The `entries` table has somewhere between 2 and 3 million rows.

```
# Time: 120121 22:24:44
# User@Host: bt_user[bt_user] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3910.984208  Lock_time: 0.091942 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 2092977602
SET timestamp=1327202684;
update entries set source_id = 4 where source = 'SOME_SOURCE';
```

Another bad case:

```
mysql> update entries set source_id = 7 where source = 'SOME_OTHER_SOURCE';
Query OK, 31270 rows affected (53 min 3.37 sec)
Rows matched: 31270  Changed: 31270  Warnings: 0

# Time: 120121 23:43:36
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3183.845250  Lock_time: 0.000110 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 875871174
SET timestamp=1327207416;
update entries set source_id = 7 where source = 'SOME_OTHER_SOURCE';
```

Here is a more normal case:

```
mysql> update entries set source_id = 6 where source = 'YET_ANOTHER_SOURCE';
Query OK, 138592 rows affected (23.84 sec)
Rows matched: 138592  Changed: 138592  Warnings: 0

# Time: 120121 22:49:54
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 23.843946  Lock_time: 0.000149 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 554368
SET timestamp=1327204194;
update entries set source_id = 6 where source = 'YET_ANOTHER_SOURCE';
```

Any idea what the deal is with the **very** large **Rows_examined**? If I can determine that, I'll understand maybe why the problematic transactions took over an hour to execute.

---

If you need more information, just ask and I'll try to provide it. Thanks for helping!

```
mysql> show create table entries\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: entries
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
  `ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(2038) DEFAULT NULL,
  `info` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `md5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `end_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `both_date_source_index` (`start_date`,`end_date`,`source`),
  KEY `source_index` (`source`),
  KEY `ip_index` (`ip`),
  KEY `domain_part_index` (`domain`(20)),
  KEY `url_part_index` (`url`(30)),
  KEY `md5_index` (`md5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2355472 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The indexing may need some review, but if that's affecting my problem...

My triggers (there is probably a better way to do this):

```
mysql> show triggers\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Trigger: after_insert_count
               Event: INSERT
               Table: entries
           Statement: BEGIN

    IF NEW.ip IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_counts WHERE ip = NEW.ip) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE ip_counts SET count = count+1 WHERE ip = NEW.ip;
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO ip_counts (ip, count) VALUES (NEW.ip, 1);
      END IF;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.domain IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domain_counts WHERE domain = NEW.domain) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE domain_counts SET count = count+1 WHERE domain = NEW.domain;
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO domain_counts (domain, count) VALUES (NEW.domain, 1);
      END IF;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.url IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM url_counts WHERE url = NEW.url) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE url_counts SET count = count+1 WHERE url = NEW.url;
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO url_counts (url, count) VALUES (NEW.url, 1);
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END
              Timing: AFTER
             Created: NULL
            sql_mode:
             Definer: root@localhost
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
*************************** 2. row ***************************
             Trigger: after_update_count
               Event: UPDATE
               Table: entries
           Statement: BEGIN

    IF OLD.ip IS NOT NULL THEN


      UPDATE ip_counts SET count = count-1 WHERE ip = OLD.ip;
    END IF;
    IF OLD.domain IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE domain_counts SET count = count-1 WHERE domain = OLD.domain;
    END IF;
    IF OLD.url IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE url_counts SET count = count-1 WHERE url = OLD.url;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.ip IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_counts WHERE ip = NEW.ip) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE ip_counts SET count = count+1 WHERE ip = NEW.ip;
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO ip_counts (ip, count) VALUES (NEW.ip, 1);
      END IF;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.domain IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domain_counts WHERE domain = NEW.domain) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE domain_counts SET count = count+1 WHERE domain = NEW.domain;
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO domain_counts (domain, count) VALUES (NEW.domain, 1);
      END IF;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.url IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM url_counts WHERE url = NEW.url) > 0 THEN
        UPDATE url_counts SET count = count+1 WHERE url = NEW.url;
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO url_counts (url, count) VALUES (NEW.url, 1);
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END
              Timing: AFTER
             Created: NULL
            sql_mode:
             Definer: root@localhost
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
*************************** 3. row ***************************
             Trigger: after_delete_count
               Event: DELETE
               Table: entries
           Statement: BEGIN

    IF OLD.ip IS NOT NULL THEN


      UPDATE ip_counts SET count = count-1 WHERE ip = OLD.ip;
    END IF;
    IF OLD.domain IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE domain_counts SET count = count-1 WHERE domain = OLD.domain;
    END IF;
    IF OLD.url IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE url_counts SET count = count-1 WHERE url = OLD.url;
    END IF;
  END
              Timing: AFTER
             Created: NULL
            sql_mode:
             Definer: root@localhost
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have any foreign key constraints in your table? Please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE entries`.

Comment: @piotrm updated my question with `show create table entries` output. Thanks for showing interest!

Comment: Any triggers? `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE \`table\`='entries'`

Comment: Yes, I have triggers -- that could be it! Maybe I could try to disable them while I run these updates? I'm pasting them right now... (ps: thanks for sticking around, if I figure this out with your help, make sure to post an answer so you can get credit!)

Comment: I'll try to follow this suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480074/mysql-disable-all-triggers and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well I'm confused about the math... and if you want to chip in on a possibly smart trigger methodology, I'd be glad to hear it. But, regarding my original question -- you solved it. After removing the triggers, everything went better than expected. Thanks so much! Post some answer so I can mark this question as solved -- maybe it'll help someone in the future (and I'd like you to get the credit for it). Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using update, insert or delete statements triggers can be responsive for extremely long query execution times and surprisingly high `Rows_examined` count in the slow_query_log file.

To see all triggers for a table use:

```
SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `table`='tblName'
```

Mysql has to run every statement in the trigger block usually affecting other tables, so Rows_examined can be just anything, not necessarily related to row count of updated table.

In your case there is a trigger called for every row affected in the update that checks whether some fields are `NOT NULL` which doesn't mean they are being actually changed but just checks if there is a non-null value for that column in a given row that qualifies for update.