# By passing triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to disable triggers while executing an update statement as it throws an error

`[Err] 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row`

I tried two solutions,

- [MySQL disable all triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480074/mysql-disable-all-triggers)
- http://www.ehow.com/how_12078894_bypass-triggers-sql.html

But none seem to work, I get the same error in the first case and in the second case I get a syntax error.

Error in 2nd case: 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER ALL'`

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Chgeck http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-disableenable-triggers-on-demand.html

Comment: isn't it better to fix your update statement? the trigger there may be required by design. if you feel the trigger is the problem fix it.

Comment: The second solution works pretty fine, take a look at the demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83501/1  If you get a syntax error in your code, then please show your code, it's hard to tell what is wrong in the code looking only on the error message.

Comment: you mean the first solution? Yes, it works fine. I thought there is some internal variable @DisableTrigger. Now, I got it.