# SQL Disabling trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I need to create a stored function which disables triggers on demand.
At first I have a parameter @disable_triggers which can I set to "all" or to specific trigger name. In the trigger I would have a variable which I assign to procedures return value and if it's true I don't execute trigger code. So in procedure I need to somehow handle the case with specific trigger name.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DisableTriggers`()
BEGIN
IF(@disable_triggers = 'all') THEN
    RETURN 1;
END IF;
IF (@disable_triggers CONTAINS 'Specific trigger name') THEN 
Return true to disable specific trigger. <<-- how to return it here.
END IF;
END
```

So the question I ask is how to handle the case with specific triggers what to return.

Comment: Tag the dbms used, this is a product specific question!

Comment: Sorry for that, there's no general solution for disabling triggers so I asked

Comment: No problem. With the (correct) product tagged your question will get better attention, and better answers, faster!

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no way to disable triggers in MySQL/MariaDB.
You can only delete triggers and re-create them later but be aware of MDL locks if you have high loaded environment.

Still you have an option to do some tricks with session variables like [MySQL disable all triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480074/mysql-disable-all-triggers)